# The Meaning of following Java code snippets

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, try-with-resources

Hi Can someone please breakdown and explain me whats the meaning of the following code fragment? e.g. What the try doing here etc.

```
try (JsonWriter jsonwriter = Json.createWriter(strwriter)) {
    jsonwriter.write(json);
}
```

Comment: It's try-with-resources: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of try-with-resources.

Documented here, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html, this is a way for Java SE7's call stack and exception-handling logic to ensure that a particular resource is closed as execution flow leaves the `try{}` block.

Any object that `implements java.lang.AutoCloseable` can be created here. Most programmers will choose to implement `java.lang.Closeable`, which also implements `AutoCloseable.`

It's like the C# `using() {}` construct.